# How do you access the commit message in a Mercurial in-process hook?

Tags: api, mercurial, pre-commit-hook, commit-message

I've been trying

```
def debug_hook(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    changectx = repo[None]
    ui.status('change.desc: %s\n' % changectx.description())
    return True
```

But it always prints an empty string. Is this because it is a precommit hook and the message isn't available yet? Or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8):

It turns out there are two things wrong with my initial approach:

1. As **jk** pointed out, the `precommit` event happens before the commit so the meta data for the commit being processed doesn't exist yet. By using `pretxncommit` instead, the meta data exists, but the transaction hasn't been committed to the database yet.
2. Using `changectx = repo[None]` gives you the change context for the working directory. But we want the info for the current commit so using `changectx = repo['tip']` instead gives us the most recent meta data.

Note that if you use `changectx = repo['tip']` with the `precommit` event, you'll actually get the last commit processed, not the current one you are working on.

Comment: yes i was slightly concerned about this from the book though "This hook can access the metadata associated with the almost-new changeset, but it should not do anything permanent with this data. It must also not modify the working directory."

Comment: This is why asking and answering your own question is encouraged on Stack Overflow. Over a year later, this answer really helped me as I was going through the [very sparse documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi) available for the HG API.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right that in precommit the message doesn't exist yet. if you use pretxncommit it will, but i'm not 100% sure what it allows you to do at that point as the transaction is almost complete.

Comment: It turns out that's part of the answer (using pretxncommit). I'll post  an answer with the details.